# Display Related Posts by Category in Random

Tags: posts, categories

I use one of smthemes and there is this code in theme to show related post. it shows the last created related posts, but I want to show related post by random, How can I do that?

```
global $SMTheme;
if ($SMTheme->get( 'layout', 'related' )) { ?>
                <div class="related-posts">
                <h3><?php echo $SMTheme->_( 'relatedposts' )?>:</h3><ul>
    <?php
    $postid=$post->ID;
    $showed_posts=array();
    $tags=get_the_tags($postid);
    $categories = get_the_category($postid);
    $post_cnt=0;
    $first=0;

    if ($categories&&($post_cnt<$SMTheme->get( 'layout', 'relatedcnt' ))) {
        $category_ids = array();
        foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
        $showed_posts[]=$postid;
        $args=array(
        'category__in' => $category_ids,
        'post__not_in' => $showed_posts,
        'showposts'=>$SMTheme->get( 'layout', 'relatedcnt' )-$post_cnt,
        'caller_get_posts'=>1);
        $posts=get_posts($args);
        if( count($posts)>0 ) {
            foreach ($posts as $p) {
                $ttl=iconv_substr( $p->post_title, 0, 150, 'utf-8' );
                ?>
                <li<?php echo (!($first%4))?" class='first'":""?>><?php
                $post_cnt++;
                if ($SMTheme->get( 'layout', 'colors' )) {
                    $r=rand(1,150);
                    $g=rand(1,150);
                    $b=rand(1,150);
                } else {
                    $r=$g=$b=1;
                }
                $first++;
           if(has_post_thumbnail($p->ID))  {
                ?><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($p->ID); ?>" title="<?php printf( $SMTheme->_( 'permalink' ), $p->post_title ); ?>" class='img'><?php
                echo get_the_post_thumbnail($p->ID,array(126,126), array('title'=>$p->post_title, 'alt'=>$p->post_title));
                ?></a><?php  
            } else {
                ?><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($p->ID); ?>" title="<?php printf( $SMTheme->_( 'permalink' ), $p->post_title ); ?>" class='img'><img src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/smt/article_related.png' width='126' height='126' alt='article' /></a><?php  
            }
        ?><br /><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($p->ID) ?>" title="<?php printf( $SMTheme->_( 'permalink' ), $p->post_title ); ?>" rel="bookmark" class="related-ttl"><div class='related-bg' style='background:rgb(<?php echo $r.",".$g.",".$b?>)'></div><span><?php echo $p->post_title ?></span></a></li>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }

    if (!$post_cnt) {
        ?><p><?php echo $SMTheme->_( 'norelatedposts' )?></p><?php
    }
    ?></ul></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the arguments for [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), add `'orderby' => 'rand'`. See [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) in Codex for a full list of available arguments.

```
$args = array(
    'category__in' => $category_ids,
    'post__not_in' => $showed_posts,
    'showposts' => $SMTheme->get( 'layout', 'relatedcnt' )-$post_cnt,
    'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);
```